# Display the next frame of sprite GDI

Tags: gdi+

I've a sprite which contains a lot of images. I see the BitBlt only display the position and imageWidth and imageHeight.

If I want to display a bitmap but only from Width[24] to Width[48] not from the beginning of that bitmap

Thanks for reading this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `BitBlt` signature:

```
BOOL BitBlt(
  __in  HDC hdcDest,
  __in  int nXDest,
  __in  int nYDest,
  __in  int nWidth,
  __in  int nHeight,
  __in  HDC hdcSrc,
  __in  int nXSrc,
  __in  int nYSrc,
  __in  DWORD dwRop
);
```

To copy only part of the source onto your destination DC, you would use nXSrc = 24 and nWidth = 24 (to match your example of copying from columns 24 through 48).

Comment: It's really stupid that I've implemented this but I didn't realize it's changed :) . Anyway thanks